# phpmyadmin not working after php verion Update

Tags: php, nginx, phpmyadmin, htaccess, mariadb

I have VPS with below things installed

Nginx, PHP 7.2.22, 10.3.18-MariaDB

Recently Updated PHP version from 7.1.17 to 7.2.22 .. After this, website is working fine.. PHPMyAdmin set on custom directory with password protection is not working.. Receiving below error

> An error occurred. Sorry, the page you are looking for is currently
>   unavailable. Please try again later.
>
> If you are the system administrator of this resource then you should
>   check the error log for details.
>
> Faithfully yours, nginx.

My Nginx configuration for domain looks something like this

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  domain.cc www.domain.cc;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
server {

    server_name domain.tv w2.domain.co domain.co domain.co;
    #return 301 https://domain.cc$request_uri;
    rewrite ^ $scheme://domain.cc$request_uri permanent;
}
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name domain.cc www.domain.cc;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/domain.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/domain.key;

    #charset koi8-r;
    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;
    error_log   /home/nginx/domain.cc/log/error.log      error;
    #root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    root   /home/nginx/domain.cc/public_html;

    location / {
    #    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    #    index  index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
    }


    #error_page  404              /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
    location /ScopephpAdmin {
        auth_basic "Admin Login";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
    }


    # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
    #}

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #    root           html;
    #    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    #    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    #    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
    #    include        fastcgi_params;
    #}

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #    deny  all;
    #}
        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/php.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/staticfiles.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/block.conf;
}
```

Kindly help me resolve this issue.